# PHP5.2 and PHP5.3 Maxing CPU on IIS7.5 Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, php5, shared-hosting, php53

I have a shared server running Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5 - the server has about 200GB ram, Several hundred websites dual Xeon 8 core hyperthreaded processors, so CPU shouldn't be a problem; What is happening, is the PHP-CGI.exe processes are stacking up and not necessarily dieing in a timely fashion. But the issue is that I get about 30+ PHP-CGI.exe processes running for 50sec - 1.5min sitting at ~4% CPU each, which effectively kills the CPU on the box, 100%. Is there any way to limit php-cgi.exe as a whole even when IIS is running them as individual application pools? I need to find a way to eliminate the opportunity for PHP-CGI.exe to 100% my CPU even if it is only using 4% at a time.

Additionally - I am running php 5.2.17 as the default handler, and have also php5.3 running as a secondary handler - this issue seems to only stack on application pools using 5.2.17

Looking for anyone who has seen similar issues, and has found a fix, or knows a way to limit the total CPU that PHP-CGI.exe can consume even when it is being used individually by separate application pools.

Thank you for reading,
jfulleton

Comment: I don't think I'll ever understand why people insist on running PHP on Windows.

Comment: Tom, if I were running my own hosting company I wouldn't even run windows servers, but the sad fact is that we have to meet customer demands, many of which are PHP running in a windows environment.